# Llamar a una api usando certificados funciona en windows, pero tira error dentro de un contenedor docker

Tags: c#, docker

El siguiente codigo lee de un par de archivos un certificado (crt) y una clave (key) para generar un certificado pfx para llamar a una api y que la llamada sea validada.

```
string rutabase = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "certs");
string rutaCertificado = Path.Combine(rutabase,"uno.crt");
string rutaKey = Path.Combine(rutabase, "dos.key");
var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(rutaCertificado,rutaKey);
certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
string URI = "la url valida";
using var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
using var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI);
```

En windows, pasa como si nada, las llamadas no tienen problema y se ejecutan sin ningún problema.

Ahora, cuando esto mismo lo meto dentro de un contenedor docker, que no es windows, entonces las llamadas fallan con el mensaje

> ERROR
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.? [?] - MESSAGE: Connection id
> "0HMUAHLB6C8TN", Request id "0HMUAHLB6C8TN:00000001": An unhandled
> exception was thrown by the application.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be
> established, see inner exception.

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
> certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain:
> PartialChain

Pero, le estoy pegando exactamente al mismo servidor.

¿Por qué puede ser que en windows no falle, pero desde dentro del contenedor sí?

Comment: Tal vez sea esto: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/71715 ?

Comment: upa interesante, ahi lo pruebo... @PatricioMoracho

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ahi arman una cadena. yo tengo un solo certificado, pero lo voy a probar bien a ver si cambia algo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los certificados dentro de un contenedor docker, deben estar ubicados dentro de un volumen montado por el composer (esto es, para evitar tener que rearmar la imagen cada vez que cambien), dentro de la carpeta (si es un contenedor linux) etc/ssl/certs.

El certificado que valida el servidor y todos sus certificados intermedios son los que hay que montar. No asi, el certificado con el que se llama.

Para montar los certificados, con toda su cadena, basta con hacer en el compose

```
volumes:
  - ./certs/ca-certificates.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

El certificado montado es la misma cadena de certificados que se usa para validar la conexion en windows.